# Sharing entity with other microservice

Tags: spring, postgresql, architecture, microservices, software-design

There is a microservice in Spring with PostgreSQL database responsible for some `Product` entity.
As there is a lot of `Product`'s and they are still growing exponentially we want to archive this data to other database (also PostgreSQL as we have best knowledge about it and we are limited by support of some other tool). In our main microservice (`Product`) is already happening lot of things so we want to extract archiving data to other job/microservice. We use migration tool in main microservice which is responsible for `Product` table changes.

Question: how to keep our `Product` entity synced with this new technical (archiving) microservice to let this new microservice always be able to get data from DB and push it in same state to other DB with same schema?

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

The point of microservices is that each service has a narrow, clearly defined set of responsibilities, allowing them to be deployed independently of each other.

If you do this then your entity code will have two sets of responsibilities, and changes that might help it do something in one service might be unneeded or even cause issues in another. It complicates deployment and testing.

Better to keep separate code bases, allow the two services to evolve independently, and live with some duplication.

There is also the question of why an archive job would need jpa entities, this sounds more like a job for a bulk copy tool or replication service than jpa. Very likely this isn't the right technical choice, you'll have a very slow archive process that will end up getting rewritten to not use jpa and this effort to reuse the entity will have been wasted.